# Advanced Multidimensional PHP JSON Parsing Issue

Tags: php, json, multidimensional-array

I have a large multidimensional JSON array that I am trying to parse with PHP (needs to be PHP due to constraints).  I have the below in a variable and then I am doing a

json_decode on this string.  I have tried with and without true to save as an array.

$json = json_decode($result,true);

then I try and reference even something simple like

$json['data']['cfgversion'] and it doesn't work.  I have also tried it without the true and using $json->data->cfgversion

What I am trying to get at is

"port_overrides": [{
            "port_idx": 6,
            "portconf_id": "59d18fe9b6081ed3f75d3355"
        }, {
            "autoneg": true,
            "isolation": false,
            "name": "Port 8",
            "op_mode": "switch",
            "poe_mode": "passthrough",
            "port_idx": 8,
            "portconf_id": "575797d9429272985a1db175",
            "stormctrl_bcast_enabled": false,
            "stormctrl_mcast_enabled": false,
            "stormctrl_ucast_enabled": false
        }],

I want to modify thing like portconf_id in that array and then push it back (this is for a Unifi Switch)

Any ideas would be great.  I have looked at the other JSOn PHP parsing answers and they don't seem to work for me with the below.  thanks in advance.

```
{
"data": [{
    "_id": "599cab6084aa6b25d7e356cd",
    "_uptime": 1857874,
    "adopted": true,
    "board_rev": 10,
    "bytes": 1057778283548,
    "cfgversion": "9ef05412066832e5",
    "config_network": {
        "dns1": "10.0.1.1",
        "dns2": "8.8.8.8",
        "gateway": "10.0.1.1",
        "ip": "10.0.1.15",
        "netmask": "255.255.255.0",
        "type": "static"
    },
    "connect_request_ip": "10.0.1.15",
    "connect_request_port": "42723",
    "considered_lost_at": 1510378663,
    "device_id": "599cab6084aa6b25d7e356cd",
    "dhcp_server_table": [],
    "dot1x_portctrl_enabled": false,
    "downlink_table": [{
        "full_duplex": true,
        "mac": "80:2a:a8:53:77:4b",
        "port_idx": 8,
        "speed": 1000
    }],
    "ethernet_table": [{
        "mac": "f0:9f:c2:1e:3c:d1",
        "name": "eth0",
        "num_port": 8
    }, {
        "mac": "f0:9f:c2:1e:3c:d2",
        "name": "srv0"
    }],
    "flowctrl_enabled": false,
    "fw_caps": 7685,
    "general_temperature": 0,
    "guest-num_sta": 0,
    "has_fan": false,
    "inform_authkey": "543fcde7cd54091e622a93686d1b3ecb",
    "inform_ip": "10.0.1.52",
    "inform_url": "http://10.0.1.52:8080/inform",
    "ip": "10.0.1.15",
    "jumboframe_enabled": false,
    "known_cfgversion": "9ef05412066832e5",
    "last_seen": 1510378492,
    "led_override": "default",
    "license_state": "registered",
    "locating": false,
    "mac": "f0:9f:c2:1e:3c:d1",
    "model": "US8",
    "name": "TV Room Switch",
    "next_heartbeat_at": 1510378549,
    "num_sta": 6,
    "overheating": false,
    "port_overrides": [{
        "port_idx": 6,
        "portconf_id": "59d18fe9b6081ed3f75d3355"
    }, {
        "autoneg": true,
        "isolation": false,
        "name": "Port 8",
        "op_mode": "switch",
        "poe_mode": "passthrough",
        "port_idx": 8,
        "portconf_id": "575797d9429272985a1db175",
        "stormctrl_bcast_enabled": false,
        "stormctrl_mcast_enabled": false,
        "stormctrl_ucast_enabled": false
    }],
    "port_table": [{
        "aggregated_by": false,
        "autoneg": true,
        "bytes-r": 11439,
        "dot1x_mode": "auto",
        "dot1x_status": "authorized",
        "enable": true,
        "flowctrl_rx": false,
        "flowctrl_tx": false,
        "full_duplex": true,
        "is_uplink": true,
        "jumbo": false,
        "lldp_table": [{
            "lldp_chassis_id": "80:2A:A8:5D:92:A4",
            "lldp_port_id": "0/15",
            "lldp_system_name": "MainSwitch"
        }],
        "masked": false,
        "media": "GE",
        "name": "Port 1",
        "op_mode": "switch",
        "poe_caps": 0,
        "port_idx": 1,
        "port_poe": false,
        "portconf_id": "575797d9429272985a1db175",
        "rx_broadcast": 5988397,
        "rx_bytes": 396387817490,
        "rx_bytes-r": 2372,
        "rx_dropped": 92655,
        "rx_errors": 0,
        "rx_multicast": 8148687,
        "rx_packets": 606001308,
        "speed": 1000,
        "stp_pathcost": 0,
        "stp_state": "forwarding",
        "tx_broadcast": 1142032,
        "tx_bytes": 661390466058,
        "tx_bytes-r": 9066,
        "tx_dropped": 0,
        "tx_errors": 0,
        "tx_multicast": 871097,
        "tx_packets": 676585183,
        "up": true
    }, {
        "aggregated_by": false,
        "autoneg": true,
        "bytes-r": 2415,
        "dot1x_mode": "auto",
        "dot1x_status": "authorized",
        "enable": true,
        "flowctrl_rx": false,
        "flowctrl_tx": false,
        "full_duplex": true,
        "is_uplink": false,
        "jumbo": false,
        "lldp_table": [],
        "masked": false,
        "media": "GE",
        "name": "Port 2",
        "op_mode": "switch",
        "poe_caps": 0,
        "port_idx": 2,
        "port_poe": false,
        "portconf_id": "575797d9429272985a1db175",
        "rx_broadcast": 72457,
        "rx_bytes": 3344218780,
        "rx_bytes-r": 507,
        "rx_dropped": 3542,
        "rx_errors": 0,
        "rx_multicast": 144549,
        "rx_packets": 36641209,
        "speed": 1000,
        "stp_pathcost": 0,
        "stp_state": "forwarding",
        "tx_broadcast": 7058001,
        "tx_bytes": 160950919257,
        "tx_bytes-r": 1907,
        "tx_dropped": 0,
        "tx_errors": 0,
        "tx_multicast": 8813991,
        "tx_packets": 125070289,
        "up": true
    }, {
        "aggregated_by": false,
        "autoneg": true,
        "bytes-r": 10396,
        "dot1x_mode": "auto",
        "dot1x_status": "authorized",
        "enable": true,
        "flowctrl_rx": false,
        "flowctrl_tx": false,
        "full_duplex": true,
        "is_uplink": false,
        "jumbo": false,
        "lldp_table": [],
        "masked": false,
        "media": "GE",
        "name": "Port 3",
        "op_mode": "switch",
        "poe_caps": 0,
        "port_idx": 3,
        "port_poe": false,
        "portconf_id": "575797d9429272985a1db175",
        "rx_broadcast": 77,
        "rx_bytes": 3384400206,
        "rx_bytes-r": 8063,
        "rx_dropped": 0,
        "rx_errors": 0,
        "rx_multicast": 4150,
        "rx_packets": 6039069,
        "speed": 100,
        "stp_pathcost": 0,
        "stp_state": "forwarding",
        "tx_broadcast": 7130309,
        "tx_bytes": 3249279910,
        "tx_bytes-r": 2332,
        "tx_dropped": 0,
        "tx_errors": 0,
        "tx_multicast": 8954291,
        "tx_packets": 19408520,
        "up": true
    }, {
        "aggregated_by": false,
        "autoneg": true,
        "bytes-r": 0,
        "dot1x_mode": "n/a",
        "dot1x_status": "n/a",
        "enable": true,
        "flowctrl_rx": false,
        "flowctrl_tx": false,
        "full_duplex": false,
        "is_uplink": false,
        "jumbo": false,
        "lldp_table": [],
        "masked": false,
        "media": "GE",
        "name": "Port 4",
        "op_mode": "switch",
        "poe_caps": 0,
        "port_idx": 4,
        "port_poe": false,
        "portconf_id": "575797d9429272985a1db175",
        "rx_broadcast": 0,
        "rx_bytes": 0,
        "rx_bytes-r": 0,
        "rx_dropped": 0,
        "rx_errors": 0,
        "rx_multicast": 0,
        "rx_packets": 0,
        "speed": 0,
        "stp_pathcost": 0,
        "stp_state": "disabled",
        "tx_broadcast": 0,
        "tx_bytes": 0,
        "tx_bytes-r": 0,
        "tx_dropped": 0,
        "tx_errors": 0,
        "tx_multicast": 0,
        "tx_packets": 0,
        "up": false
    }, {
        "aggregated_by": false,
        "autoneg": true,
        "bytes-r": 0,
        "dot1x_mode": "n/a",
        "dot1x_status": "n/a",
        "enable": true,
        "flowctrl_rx": false,
        "flowctrl_tx": false,
        "full_duplex": false,
        "is_uplink": false,
        "jumbo": false,
        "lldp_table": [],
        "masked": false,
        "media": "GE",
        "name": "Port 5",
        "op_mode": "switch",
        "poe_caps": 0,
        "port_idx": 5,
        "port_poe": false,
        "portconf_id": "575797d9429272985a1db175",
        "rx_broadcast": 0,
        "rx_bytes": 0,
        "rx_bytes-r": 0,
        "rx_dropped": 0,
        "rx_errors": 0,
        "rx_multicast": 0,
        "rx_packets": 0,
        "speed": 0,
        "stp_pathcost": 0,
        "stp_state": "disabled",
        "tx_broadcast": 0,
        "tx_bytes": 0,
        "tx_bytes-r": 0,
        "tx_dropped": 0,
        "tx_errors": 0,
        "tx_multicast": 0,
        "tx_packets": 0,
        "up": false
    }, {
        "aggregated_by": false,
        "autoneg": true,
        "bytes-r": 0,
        "dot1x_mode": "n/a",
        "dot1x_status": "n/a",
        "enable": true,
        "flowctrl_rx": false,
        "flowctrl_tx": false,
        "full_duplex": false,
        "is_uplink": false,
        "jumbo": false,
        "lldp_table": [],
        "masked": false,
        "media": "GE",
        "name": "Port 6",
        "op_mode": "switch",
        "poe_caps": 0,
        "port_idx": 6,
        "port_poe": false,
        "portconf_id": "59d18fe9b6081ed3f75d3355",
        "rx_broadcast": 0,
        "rx_bytes": 0,
        "rx_bytes-r": 0,
        "rx_dropped": 0,
        "rx_errors": 0,
        "rx_multicast": 0,
        "rx_packets": 0,
        "speed": 0,
        "stp_pathcost": 0,
        "stp_state": "disabled",
        "tx_broadcast": 0,
        "tx_bytes": 0,
        "tx_bytes-r": 0,
        "tx_dropped": 0,
        "tx_errors": 0,
        "tx_multicast": 0,
        "tx_packets": 0,
        "up": false
    }, {
        "aggregated_by": false,
        "autoneg": true,
        "bytes-r": 0,
        "dot1x_mode": "n/a",
        "dot1x_status": "n/a",
        "enable": true,
        "flowctrl_rx": false,
        "flowctrl_tx": false,
        "full_duplex": false,
        "is_uplink": false,
        "jumbo": false,
        "lldp_table": [],
        "masked": false,
        "media": "GE",
        "name": "Port 7",
        "op_mode": "switch",
        "poe_caps": 0,
        "port_idx": 7,
        "port_poe": false,
        "portconf_id": "575797d9429272985a1db175",
        "rx_broadcast": 0,
        "rx_bytes": 0,
        "rx_bytes-r": 0,
        "rx_dropped": 0,
        "rx_errors": 0,
        "rx_multicast": 0,
        "rx_packets": 0,
        "speed": 0,
        "stp_pathcost": 0,
        "stp_state": "disabled",
        "tx_broadcast": 0,
        "tx_bytes": 0,
        "tx_bytes-r": 0,
        "tx_dropped": 0,
        "tx_errors": 0,
        "tx_multicast": 0,
        "tx_packets": 0,
        "up": false
    }, {
        "aggregated_by": false,
        "autoneg": true,
        "bytes-r": 2226,
        "dot1x_mode": "auto",
        "dot1x_status": "authorized",
        "enable": true,
        "flowctrl_rx": false,
        "flowctrl_tx": false,
        "full_duplex": true,
        "is_uplink": false,
        "isolation": false,
        "jumbo": false,
        "lldp_table": [],
        "masked": false,
        "media": "GE",
        "name": "Port 8",
        "op_mode": "switch",
        "poe_caps": 8,
        "poe_enable": true,
        "poe_mode": "passthrough",
        "poe_voltage": "48.00",
        "port_idx": 8,
        "port_poe": true,
        "portconf_id": "575797d9429272985a1db175",
        "rx_broadcast": 1012063,
        "rx_bytes": 655667898453,
        "rx_bytes-r": 362,
        "rx_dropped": 28656,
        "rx_errors": 0,
        "rx_multicast": 630304,
        "rx_packets": 634872135,
        "speed": 1000,
        "stormctrl_bcast_enabled": false,
        "stormctrl_mcast_enabled": false,
        "stormctrl_ucast_enabled": false,
        "stp_pathcost": 0,
        "stp_state": "forwarding",
        "tx_broadcast": 6116174,
        "tx_bytes": 239145629938,
        "tx_bytes-r": 1864,
        "tx_dropped": 0,
        "tx_errors": 0,
        "tx_multicast": 8341073,
        "tx_packets": 495246848,
        "up": true
    }],
    "power_source": "poe",
    "power_source_voltage": "48.00",
    "rx_bytes": 661390466058,
    "serial": "F09FC21E3CD1",
    "site_id": "575797d7429272985a1db16c",
    "ssh_session_table": [],
    "stat": {
        "bytes": 3.90939602E8,
        "datetime": "2017-11-11T04:10:00Z",
        "duration": 4950000.0,
        "o": "sw",
        "oid": "f0:9f:c2:1e:3c:d1",
        "port_1-rx_bytes": 6.9195452E7,
        "port_1-rx_dropped": 304.0,
        "port_1-rx_packets": 181516.0,
        "port_1-tx_bytes": 1.16929998E8,
        "port_1-tx_packets": 168689.0,
        "port_2-rx_bytes": 3303986.0,
        "port_2-rx_dropped": 9.0,
        "port_2-rx_packets": 11352.0,
        "port_2-tx_bytes": 1.0588899E7,
        "port_2-tx_packets": 56442.0,
        "port_3-rx_bytes": 8936568.0,
        "port_3-rx_packets": 15892.0,
        "port_3-tx_bytes": 1.1060388E7,
        "port_3-tx_packets": 61268.0,
        "port_8-rx_bytes": 1.04055643E8,
        "port_8-rx_dropped": 89.0,
        "port_8-rx_packets": 140018.0,
        "port_8-tx_bytes": 6.6868668E7,
        "port_8-tx_packets": 164236.0,
        "rx_bytes": 1.85491649E8,
        "rx_crypts": 0.0,
        "rx_dropped": 402.0,
        "rx_errors": 0.0,
        "rx_frags": 0.0,
        "rx_packets": 348778.0,
        "site_id": "575797d7429272985a1db16c",
        "sw": "f0:9f:c2:1e:3c:d1",
        "time": 1510373400000,
        "tx_bytes": 2.05447953E8,
        "tx_dropped": 0.0,
        "tx_errors": 0.0,
        "tx_packets": 450635.0,
        "tx_retries": 0.0
    },
    "state": 1,
    "stp_priority": "32768",
    "stp_version": "rstp",
    "sys_stats": {
        "loadavg_1": "1.26",
        "loadavg_15": "1.41",
        "loadavg_5": "1.31",
        "mem_buffer": 0,
        "mem_total": 262766592,
        "mem_used": 161001472
    },
    "tx_bytes": 396387817490,
    "type": "usw",
    "uplink": {
        "full_duplex": true,
        "ip": "10.0.1.15",
        "mac": "f0:9f:c2:1e:3c:d1",
        "max_speed": 1000,
        "media": "GE",
        "name": "eth0",
        "netmask": "255.255.255.0",
        "num_port": 8,
        "port_idx": 1,
        "rx_bytes": 396387817490,
        "rx_bytes-r": 2372,
        "rx_dropped": 92655,
        "rx_errors": 0,
        "rx_multicast": 0,
        "rx_packets": 606001308,
        "speed": 1000,
        "tx_bytes": 661390466058,
        "tx_bytes-r": 9066,
        "tx_dropped": 0,
        "tx_errors": 0,
        "tx_packets": 676585183,
        "type": "wire",
        "up": true,
        "uplink_mac": "80:2a:a8:5d:92:a4"
    },
    "uplink_depth": 2,
    "uptime": 1857874,
    "user-num_sta": 6,
    "version": "3.9.3.7537",
    "x_authkey": "543fcde7cd54091e622a93686d1b3ecb",
    "x_fingerprint": "65:06:32:75:3a:af:99:8a:92:14:0e:1d:6d:3f:6b:7b",
    "x_has_ssh_hostkey": true,
    "x_ssh_hostkey_fingerprint": "65:06:32:75:3a:af:99:8a:92:14:0e:1d:6d:3f:6b:7b"
}],
"meta": {
    "rc": "ok"
}
```

}

Comment: Its an array, you should be doing `$json['data'][0]['cfgversion']`

Comment: Yep that was it thanks that made it so I could figure out a lot of other things I want to do with the Arrays in PHP.

Comment: Dumb question but how do I choose your answer as the correct one in here?  I can't find where is allows that

Comment: Im meant to put my answer down below before you could do that ;p glad it worked happy coding :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lawrence has the correct answer

> Its an array, you should be doing `$json['data'][0]['cfgversion']`